# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение типа: "Он сам знает(,) зачем это делает". Нужна запятая перед "зачем" или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужна. Предложение сложноподчиненное, перед придаточной частью - запятая.